# Why does moment() return n inside $q?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

In the following code, `$scope.recentUnreported.push` is filled with different values of `i` as I expect.

```
    $scope.getRecentReported = function () {
      var promises = [];
      for (i = 0; i < $scope.recentDateLength; i++) {
        var dateThen = moment().add(-i, 'days');
        promises.push(RestRequestsSrvc.getRevenue(dateThen));
      }
      $q.all(promises).then(function(response){
        for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
          if (!response[i]) {
            $scope.recentUnreported.push(i);
          }
        }
      });
    };
```

In the following code, `$scope.recentUnreported.push` is filled with `'n'` values instead of dates. Why is that?

```
    $scope.getRecentReported = function () {
      var promises = [];
      for (i = 0; i < $scope.recentDateLength; i++) {
        var dateThen = moment().add(-i, 'days');
        promises.push(RestRequestsSrvc.getRevenue(dateThen));
      }
      $q.all(promises).then(function(response){
        for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
          if (!response[i]) {
            $scope.recentUnreported.push(moment());
          }
        }
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using moment correctly, try

```
 $scope.recentUnreported.push(moment().format());
```